# How to call a particular Tab Activity from other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

I have created 3 tabs using tabhost in the MaintabActivity;

1. TaboneActivity
2. TabtwoActivity
3. TabthreeActivity

there is a button in the TabtwoActivity, when i click on it , anohter activity called OutofServiceActivity.java is displayed.
my problem is when iam trying to call TabtwoActivity from OutofServiceActivity.java it will  rediect to TabtwoActivity without showing the tab bar..?
what s the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Give a call to `TabHost.setCurrentTab(--tab id here--)` in `onCreate` method when you set your activities.

Comment: I already set tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); it in the MaintabActivity .but when i use Intent back=new Intent(AllocationDetails.this,Tabtwo.class) ; it shows the content without tab bar, ie;showing only xml file of tabtwo

Comment: Can you please share your code, it will be helpful in alleviating your problem.

Comment: i just want to call a tab from other activity